# Java view template library

Tags: java, templates, datatemplate, markup, velocity

I need a Java library allowing me to define my own tags / commands and then creating html output based on a given data-model.

In example I'd like the library to handle such a situation:

```
String template = "<name>key1</name><image>key1</image>"
map.put("key1", imageObject);
String html = parser.parse(template, map);
html == "<i>An Image</i><img src='image.jpg'/>"
```

So the basic functionality would be to generate html based on the **custom tag** (e.g. `<name>`) - each tag would generate different output.

I.e. `name` would print a string, whereas `image` would place an image. The `imageObject` has appropriate fields that the parsing library can reach.

Kind regards,

Queequeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) can be suitable in your case

Comment: can I define a class that handles a part of parsing? I.e. when velocity finds an `<image>` tag it sends the value of the tag to a custom Java handler and the class returns a string?

Comment: Absolutely yes. It will take 15 minutes to understand the main principles of this framework, take a look

Comment: Okay, I will immediately look into this

Comment: Can you give me a hint/link regarding customizing Velocity behavior?

Comment: Maybe these pages will help: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Velocity_and_XML   and http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/veltag.html

Answer (score 0):

Except Velocity, it worth looking at another two template engines FreeMarker and StringTemplate.

There is enough resources to take decision which to use, but probably StringTemplate is enough.